# Changing vega lite markLine to markBar makes it loose sort order

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega, vega-lite-api

I have made following visualization:

```js
data = [{"student_name": "student 0", "e": "100.15", "d": "127.81"}, {"student_name": "student 1", "e": "100.30", "d": "189.94"}, {"student_name": "student 2", "e": "100.15", "d": "105.33"}, {"student_name": "student 3", "e": "99.41", "d": "85.36"}, {"student_name": "student 4", "e": "100.00", "d": "203.70"}, {"student_name": "student 5", "e": "100.15", "d": "139.05"}, {"student_name": "student 6", "e": "41.72", "d": "41.72"}, {"student_name": "student 7", "e": "100.30", "d": "260.50"}, {"student_name": "student 8", "e": "92.60", "d": "94.53"}, {"student_name": "student 9", "e": "99.11", "d": "86.39"}, {"student_name": "student 10", "e": "97.49", "d": "92.46"}, {"student_name": "student 11", "e": "98.37", "d": "83.58"}, {"student_name": "student 12", "e": "100.15", "d": "182.40"}, {"student_name": "student 13", "e": "100.15", "d": "99.41"}, {"student_name": "student 14", "e": "86.69", "d": "81.95"}, {"student_name": "student 15", "e": "98.08", "d": "306.51"}, {"student_name": "student 16", "e": "100.15", "d": "86.54"}, {"student_name": "student 17", "e": "100.15", "d": "186.39"}, {"student_name": "student 18", "e": "99.26", "d": "93.64"}, {"student_name": "student 19", "e": "100.15", "d": "102.66"}, {"student_name": "student 20", "e": "95.71", "d": "52.96"}, {"student_name": "student 21", "e": "99.85", "d": "99.41"}, {"student_name": "student 22", "e": "98.96", "d": "100.44"}, {"student_name": "student 23", "e": "100.15", "d": "131.07"}, {"student_name": "student 24", "e": "99.56", "d": "76.92"}, {"student_name": "student 25", "e": "100.15", "d": "213.46"}, {"student_name": "student 26", "e": "100.15", "d": "311.24"}, {"student_name": "student 27", "e": "100.15", "d": "21.89"}, {"student_name": "student 28", "e": "96.60", "d": "6.36"}, {"student_name": "student 29", "e": "53.70", "d": "3.70"}, {"student_name": "student 30", "e": "96.75", "d": "46.60"}, {"student_name": "student 31", "e": "100.15", "d": "100.15"}, {"student_name": "student 32", "e": "100.30", "d": "115.68"}, {"student_name": "student 33", "e": "87.13", "d": "103.85"}, {"student_name": "student 34", "e": "100.15", "d": "104.14"}]

createChart = function (data) {
  max_d = d3.max(data, record => parseFloat(record.d));
  max_e = d3.max(data, record => parseFloat(record.e));
  max_y_scale_value_for_d = d3.max([100, max_d]);
  max_y_scale_value_for_e = d3.max([100, max_e]);

  const mpg = vl.markLine()
              .data(data)
              .transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
              
              .encode(
                      vl.x()
                        .fieldN('student_name')
                        .title('students')
                        .axis({ labels: false, ticks: false })
                        .sort('-y'),
                      vl.y()
                        .fieldQ('d2')
                        .scale({ "domain": [0, max_y_scale_value_for_d] })
                        .title('D'),        
                      vl.tooltip([{ 'field': 'student_name', 'title': 'Sudent Name' },
                                  { 'field': 'd', 'title': 'D' },
                                  { 'field': 'e', 'title': 'E' }])
                                ).width(500).height(250);

  const hp = mpg.markLine({ color: '#227a15' })     
              .encode(
                      vl.y()
                        .fieldQ('e2')
                        .scale({ "domain": [0, max_y_scale_value_for_e] })
                        .title('E')
                     );

  const plot = vl.vconcat(
                       vl.layer(mpg, mpg.markCircle()),
                       vl.layer(hp, hp.markCircle({ color: '#227a15' }))
                     )

  return plot.toObject();
}

const chart_spec_json = this.createChart(data)
const opt = {
               renderer: "canvas",
               actions: false
            };
vegaEmbed("#stats", chart_spec_json, opt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega@5.21.0/build/vega.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega-lite@5.2.0/build/vega-lite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/vega-embed@6.20.8/build/vega-embed.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega-lite-api@5.0.0/build/vega-lite-api.min.js"></script>
<div id="stats" />
```

It renders as follows (run above script to see it in action):

[image]

But when I change `markLine()` to `mmarkBar()`, the top blue `D` graph looses its sort order with the warning `WARN Domains that should be unioned has conflicting sort properties. Sort will be set to true.`:

[image]

```js
data = [{"student_name": "student 0", "e": "100.15", "d": "127.81"}, {"student_name": "student 1", "e": "100.30", "d": "189.94"}, {"student_name": "student 2", "e": "100.15", "d": "105.33"}, {"student_name": "student 3", "e": "99.41", "d": "85.36"}, {"student_name": "student 4", "e": "100.00", "d": "203.70"}, {"student_name": "student 5", "e": "100.15", "d": "139.05"}, {"student_name": "student 6", "e": "41.72", "d": "41.72"}, {"student_name": "student 7", "e": "100.30", "d": "260.50"}, {"student_name": "student 8", "e": "92.60", "d": "94.53"}, {"student_name": "student 9", "e": "99.11", "d": "86.39"}, {"student_name": "student 10", "e": "97.49", "d": "92.46"}, {"student_name": "student 11", "e": "98.37", "d": "83.58"}, {"student_name": "student 12", "e": "100.15", "d": "182.40"}, {"student_name": "student 13", "e": "100.15", "d": "99.41"}, {"student_name": "student 14", "e": "86.69", "d": "81.95"}, {"student_name": "student 15", "e": "98.08", "d": "306.51"}, {"student_name": "student 16", "e": "100.15", "d": "86.54"}, {"student_name": "student 17", "e": "100.15", "d": "186.39"}, {"student_name": "student 18", "e": "99.26", "d": "93.64"}, {"student_name": "student 19", "e": "100.15", "d": "102.66"}, {"student_name": "student 20", "e": "95.71", "d": "52.96"}, {"student_name": "student 21", "e": "99.85", "d": "99.41"}, {"student_name": "student 22", "e": "98.96", "d": "100.44"}, {"student_name": "student 23", "e": "100.15", "d": "131.07"}, {"student_name": "student 24", "e": "99.56", "d": "76.92"}, {"student_name": "student 25", "e": "100.15", "d": "213.46"}, {"student_name": "student 26", "e": "100.15", "d": "311.24"}, {"student_name": "student 27", "e": "100.15", "d": "21.89"}, {"student_name": "student 28", "e": "96.60", "d": "6.36"}, {"student_name": "student 29", "e": "53.70", "d": "3.70"}, {"student_name": "student 30", "e": "96.75", "d": "46.60"}, {"student_name": "student 31", "e": "100.15", "d": "100.15"}, {"student_name": "student 32", "e": "100.30", "d": "115.68"}, {"student_name": "student 33", "e": "87.13", "d": "103.85"}, {"student_name": "student 34", "e": "100.15", "d": "104.14"}]

createChart = function (data) {
  max_d = d3.max(data, record => parseFloat(record.d));
  max_e = d3.max(data, record => parseFloat(record.e));
  max_y_scale_value_for_d = d3.max([100, max_d]);
  max_y_scale_value_for_e = d3.max([100, max_e]);

    const mpg = vl.markBar()
              .data(data)
              .transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
              
              .encode(
                      vl.x()
                        .fieldN('student_name')
                        .title('students')
                        .axis({ labels: false, ticks: false })
                        .sort('-y'),
                      vl.y()
                        .fieldQ('d2')
                        .scale({ "domain": [0, max_y_scale_value_for_d] })
                        .title('D'),        
                      vl.tooltip([{ 'field': 'student_name', 'title': 'Sudent Name' },
                                  { 'field': 'd', 'title': 'D' },
                                  { 'field': 'e', 'title': 'E' }])
                                ).width(500).height(250);

  const hp = mpg.markLine({ color: '#227a15' })     
              .encode(
                      vl.y()
                        .fieldQ('e2')
                        .scale({ "domain": [0, max_y_scale_value_for_e] })
                        .title('E')
                     );

  const plot = vl.vconcat(
                       vl.layer(mpg, mpg.markCircle()),
                       vl.layer(hp, hp.markCircle({ color: '#227a15' }))
                     )
  return plot.toObject();
}

const chart_spec_json = this.createChart(data)
const opt = {
               renderer: "canvas",
               actions: false
            };
vegaEmbed("#stats", chart_spec_json, opt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega@5.21.0/build/vega.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega-lite@5.2.0/build/vega-lite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/vega-embed@6.20.8/build/vega-embed.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vega-lite-api@5.0.0/build/vega-lite-api.min.js"></script>
<div id="stats" />
```

Run above script to see `markBar()` loose sort order. Here is the corresponding [observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/9b4e9bedd26e7799).

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `markRect` instead of `markBar`, or remove `markCircle` on top of `markBar` (do you really need circles on top of bars?)

The issue with markBar and markCircle, is that under the hood vega-lite creates a separate dataset for markBar, which might seem excessive for your case, but it becomes more useful if you'd have stacked bars. Then it tries to merge them, but it doesn't like if they both have sort order, despite it is the same order:

```js
if (isDataRefDomain(domain) && sorts.length > 0) {
      let sort = sorts[0];
      if (sorts.length > 1) {
        log.warn(log.message.MORE_THAN_ONE_SORT);
        sort = true;
```

I believe vega-lite can do a better job, checking if those sorts are the same or not, instead of checking just count, but in the meantime you can either use `markRect` which doesn't create this additional dataset, or not use `markCircle` at all.

Also I would recommend generating vega-lite spec from vega-lite-api, by calling `plot.toSpec()` and pasting it to [Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQcWVDYATGrLJpQAD10gAZjTiD1aEBEwN1KzAH1ZSBHEUhMATxxv0stghaSILumHSCvlY2drKYEO5IejTxqKCCSExmKUbBEHBKYVAA1tm5cAC+SjIATpiW-J7u0MG+oDhI6praAJKysnDVaAAMlACM5ZUgjanGpuaW6gBMod6RAI4MSLF0SGGkoeGRACIgE0rpngNoANqgyNVFltVwUHWVd0gPllA01VARpwAukp1LsUDNiMEGHAUrcorZ7E4XJFrAjYgACIbuSKjIYjUZidwWdCjRYAdkoAA5RqcFKBUTFHM5XJYGfZ0TSlDi8ZQAMxYkGWUaUgCclBFABZafToojmSjZRjllyhTyCUTVRJebzpfDGUiWeg2RidSr0CKxRLOSBiSBKVqAGy641M5GsxWYdFSs0gXEjPEa9CLIa8yhkrHvPVyt1Gj3owk+v1jBM2oW8sVDQmRl0GhVoz1On1WsPK1PoYtk5bZj259359Fk7Gqkb8wMgRYOkZiCN0qOxWux+uUpvmxaUTttyWUMQ66v5gd9z0ikcgC1ja22ykOvnLuf6+V1xkcgXKSwiikS5eC0eUCVOvfRw2LjnWyIiyl8xvXu2hsTDh-9geg5HqSK5Juq37CmOEo9jK85Ac+oymqeJJqimtprlazo1ghLoct6KF2tuDpXmWdqjOKWa9jmuFxhBhHvpQQzDt+-LbmINIAa6T54aMhaEeB6GWFu05SlxC68V+AloW2wrbum2HwTGiEsQxYodpOoYOmJ1E4cpvGkdy+JCahY4OveulKTxcbBiuIoSGSG6WGIY4ihZcH7vpNmvmeYr2pOlqcZZnnWfWiylm+H5ubJPISjpHmPnmR6LMhRnJrJvIUUMjbibRYUEW+YpiPxtpktuIpVsFiWHuyiwpml9G2osSG3u5i4STZ-ENSZICZRRizxe1eXJVJ3Vts1VK7lVgFeWFqlvsRJ62vJbU0bNyWGc5obhm222wUN63sq2PpuWGPV3uO+1raFR6ZWBMmQTJuWHSaEXNnyS1CgS47-tN3FJUdqXCRSSExaG-nPTdR0Fe9jWqhKYxiYCkyYNUWwQEYbDVAgNygFAwRQAw6SYJEmBsAAcgwCCZNUAAUoI2AglDqAAlAkKQ2pVeME0TuykxTVM0-TuxU5QcBs0oSAc3AVbAiAADuNDqPQaDdkMSjwDQZBYGgdVDOUQA), this way you'll be able to see compiled vega spec and all the auxiliary datasets generated by vega-lite.

Comment: great point in last paragraph. Sad to know implementation inconsistency in vega. Am afraid if there can be more such. **Q1.** Recently, I came across another [possible bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72072464/vega-lite-api-miss-behaving) which am not able to debug, if you can have a look. **Q.2** Is vega-lite-api automatically generated from vega-lite schema (like python altair)?  (continued...)

Comment: (...continued) **Q3.** Best source to learn vega-lite-api? I wanted to draw vertical rules in first graph to indicate 90th and 10th percentile of students. I can guess I have to use `markRule` and calculate transform. I can find vega lite example for it, but unable to figure it out how to translate it to vega-lite-api.

Comment: **Q2:** Yes.
**Q3:** I don't think I know any additional sources besides obvious ones (official documentation and collection of observable notebooks), which I think, you know yourself. Although I'm not using vega-lite-api myself a lot, I was able to implement what you are asking for: https://observablehq.com/d/14876d2b92cde823. I believe  it will come to you with more practice.

Comment: Yes, I was also able to do what you did, but I mentioned in the last comment that I wanted to draw "vertical rules" to indicate 90th and 10th percentile of students, that is I want to separate students who are in top 10% and bottom 10%. I dont want to have horizontal rules cutting Y axis, but vertical rules cutting X axis based on Y-axis values. So these will be rules going through point of intersection of rules you draw and line (or bar) graph and perpendicular to X axis. Something like blue lines in [this](https://postimg.cc/Thtn7c0L/b0d356fc) image.

Comment: Ahh, okay. That's a bit more complicated. You said there is a vega lite example for it, can you share it? Probably you can achieve it by using some kind of window + argmax transform. Or you always can use constant values calculated outside vega `vl.markRule().encode(vl.x().datum(student_q10))`

Comment: The example graph titled "IMDB Rating (binned), Mean of IMDB Rating" with red vertical rule mark is given "just above" [Ranged Rules section](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/rule.html#ranged). Am curious how this vega-lite json grammar can be translated into vega-lite-api. Will give me pointer to workflow for how to think from grammar to api code or desired visualization to api code.

Comment: Well, the example you referenced is only visually looks similar to what you want, and it should be pretty easy to replicate using vega-lite-api, but your task is quite different. In the example, there is a histogram, where **x** domain corresponds your variable values, thus any aggregates like mean/quantile will lie in the same domain.  This is basically, what I implemented above, just your target variable values lie on **y** axis, rather than **x**. What you are asking is to find **argument/index** corresponding to certain quantiles.

Comment: Out of the box they are not provided in vega's **quantile** transform (only values, no argument). So you have to somehow calculate them using combination of transforms, or maybe manually. As I said, probably you can use window function **percent_rank** followed by **argmax/argmin**, but it will more complicated than just a single line of code. Offhand, I don't know exact implementation. Probably it worth a separate question. Or as I mentioned before you can, find student name at q10/q90 using plain javascript/d3 and just pass it to vega using **datum** method.

Comment: ahh I see, its just visually same... it is finding mean of x axis values only. And yes I guess, it makes perfect sense to find the student outside vega at least to avoid unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort by -y but you have two different y encodings specified and only one x encoding. Can you try the following to see if it gives you what you want?

[image]

```
{
    let data = [{"student_name": "student 0", "e": "100.15", "d": "127.81"}, {"student_name": "student 1", "e": "100.30", "d": "189.94"}, {"student_name": "student 2", "e": "100.15", "d": "105.33"}, {"student_name": "student 3", "e": "99.41", "d": "85.36"}, {"student_name": "student 4", "e": "100.00", "d": "203.70"}, {"student_name": "student 5", "e": "100.15", "d": "139.05"}, {"student_name": "student 6", "e": "41.72", "d": "41.72"}, {"student_name": "student 7", "e": "100.30", "d": "260.50"}, {"student_name": "student 8", "e": "92.60", "d": "94.53"}, {"student_name": "student 9", "e": "99.11", "d": "86.39"}, {"student_name": "student 10", "e": "97.49", "d": "92.46"}, {"student_name": "student 11", "e": "98.37", "d": "83.58"}, {"student_name": "student 12", "e": "100.15", "d": "182.40"}, {"student_name": "student 13", "e": "100.15", "d": "99.41"}, {"student_name": "student 14", "e": "86.69", "d": "81.95"}, {"student_name": "student 15", "e": "98.08", "d": "306.51"}, {"student_name": "student 16", "e": "100.15", "d": "86.54"}, {"student_name": "student 17", "e": "100.15", "d": "186.39"}, {"student_name": "student 18", "e": "99.26", "d": "93.64"}, {"student_name": "student 19", "e": "100.15", "d": "102.66"}, {"student_name": "student 20", "e": "95.71", "d": "52.96"}, {"student_name": "student 21", "e": "99.85", "d": "99.41"}, {"student_name": "student 22", "e": "98.96", "d": "100.44"}, {"student_name": "student 23", "e": "100.15", "d": "131.07"}, {"student_name": "student 24", "e": "99.56", "d": "76.92"}, {"student_name": "student 25", "e": "100.15", "d": "213.46"}, {"student_name": "student 26", "e": "100.15", "d": "311.24"}, {"student_name": "student 27", "e": "100.15", "d": "21.89"}, {"student_name": "student 28", "e": "96.60", "d": "6.36"}, {"student_name": "student 29", "e": "53.70", "d": "3.70"}, {"student_name": "student 30", "e": "96.75", "d": "46.60"}, {"student_name": "student 31", "e": "100.15", "d": "100.15"}, {"student_name": "student 32", "e": "100.30", "d": "115.68"}, {"student_name": "student 33", "e": "87.13", "d": "103.85"}, {"student_name": "student 34", "e": "100.15", "d": "104.14"}]
  let max_d = d3.max(data, record => parseFloat(record.d));
    let max_e = d3.max(data, record => parseFloat(record.e));
    let max_y_scale_value_for_d = d3.max([100, max_d]);
    let max_y_scale_value_for_e = d3.max([100, max_e]);

  const mpg = vl.markBar()
              .data(data)
              .transform([{ "calculate": "toNumber(datum.d)", "as": "d2" }, { "calculate": "toNumber(datum.e)", "as": "e2" }])
              
              .encode(
                      vl.x()
                        .fieldN('student_name')
                        .title('students')
                        .axis({ labels: false, ticks: false })
                        .sort({field:'d2', op:"sum", order:"descending"}),
                      vl.y()
                        .fieldQ('d2')
                        .scale({ "domain": [0, max_y_scale_value_for_d] })
                        .title('D'),        
                      vl.tooltip([{ 'field': 'student_name', 'title': 'Sudent Name' },
                                  { 'field': 'd', 'title': 'D' },
                                  { 'field': 'e', 'title': 'E' }])
                                ).width(500).height(250);

  const hp = mpg.markLine({ color: '#227a15' })     
              .encode(
                vl.x()
                        .fieldN('student_name')
                        .title('students')
                        .axis({ labels: false, ticks: false })
                        .sort('-y'),
                      vl.y()
                        .fieldQ('e2')
                        .scale({ "domain": [0, max_y_scale_value_for_e] })
                        .title('E')
                     );

  const plot = vl.vconcat(
                       vl.layer(mpg, mpg.markCircle()),
                       vl.layer(hp, hp.markCircle({ color: '#227a15' }))
                     )
  
  return plot.render();
}
```

Comment: So you added `x` encoding to `hp`. I did not added because I thought doing `hp = mpg.markLine` means `hp` inherits all things from `mpg` and we have to define only those things which differ in `hp` from `mpg`. **Q1.** Isnt it? If not, what does it mean by creating one plot from other, that is, what is meant by `hp = mpg.markLine`? **Q2.** Why "specifying two different y encodings but only one x encoding" worked for `markLine` and did not work for `markBar`"?